# How to write unit test for private static method in static class with nunit in c#

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, static-methods, static-classes

I'm using nunit for unit testing and i want to test a private method in a static class.
This is my class:

```
public static class ServiceModuleExtentions
{
    public static void RegisterCoreServices(this IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
    {
        serviceCollection.AddScoped<ICourseService, CourseService>();
        var automapper = RegisterAutoMapperService();
        serviceCollection.AddSingleton(automapper);
    }

    private static IMapper RegisterAutoMapperService()
    {
        // Auto Mapper Configurations
        var mappingConfig = new MapperConfiguration(mc =>
        {
            mc.AddProfile(new MapperProfile());
        });

        IMapper mapper = mappingConfig.CreateMapper();

        return mapper;
    }
}
```

Now my question is how can i write unit test for RegisterAutoMapperService method?

And also this is my MapperProfile class:

```
public class MapperProfile : Profile
{
    public MapperProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<Course, CourseVM>().ReverseMap();
    }
}
```

Comment: You could test it indirectly by calling `BuildServiceProvider()` on the `IServiceCollection`, then using `GetRequiredService<ICourseService>()` on the returned `IServiceProvider` to construct an instance of your class. I'm not sure there's much more you could assert on that that it didn't throw an exception though.

Comment: Automapper has it's own configuration validation. [Docs](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Configuration-validation.html)